# Replace the diagonal of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I am interesting to replace the diagonal of matrix `D` to `1,2,3,4`.
This is matrix `D`:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5; 3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7];
D=[A;A];
D=[D D]; % size of matrix [4x16] %
```

Comment: what do u mean by the diagonal? D is a non-square matrix..

Comment: @Kishore, a [main diagonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal) is also defined for non-square matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the main diagonal to integers starting a 1 and incrementing by 1:

```
D(eye(4)==1) = 1:4
```

Or to generalize it:

```
n = min(size(D));
D(eye(n)==1) = 1:n;
```

note here that the `==1` is to convert the output of `eye(n)`, the identity matrix, to type logical.

**EDIT:**

This is just a guess at what you mean by all the diagonals but here goes:

```
n = size(D,1);
m = size(D,2);
I = repmat(eye(min([n,m])), ceil(n/m), ceil(m/n));
I = I(1:n, 1:m)==1
d = repmat(1:min([n,m]), 1, max([ceil(n/m), ceil(m/n)]));
d = d(1:max(m,n));
D(I) = d
```

Comment: Hello dan, This change only 1 diagonal in matrix, I want to change all diagonals in matrix.

Comment: What other diagonals? Please provide a manually calculated example and add it to your question (edit your original question) so we can see what you mean.

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as correct and upvote if you found it helpful (by clicking the arrow and the tick in the top left of this answer)